# filter data based on month start and month end

Tags: pandas, numpy, datetime

Given a dataframe with date column in this format.

```
    Date      Group 
 2020-05-18     1
 2020-06-22     1
 2019-07-11     1
 2018-03-01     1
 2021-01-21     2
 2021-05-05     2
 2021-09-11     2
```

And two strings;

```
   Start = 2020-05 (indicating month start)
   End = 2021-09   (indicating month end)
```

I want to filter out the data so that only the dates that fall within the start and end date are available in the dataframe.

Expected output:

```
          Date      Group 
       2020-05-18     1
       2020-06-22     1
       2021-01-21     2
       2021-05-05     2
       2021-09-11     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Creating dummy data
d = {'dt':['2020-05-18',
  '2020-06-22',
  '2019-07-11',
  '2018-03-01',
  '2021-01-21',
  '2021-05-05', 
  '2021-09-11'], 
  'group':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2]}

dt_df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
dt_df

dt_df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(dt_df['dt'])

dt_df
```

Inital Input:

```
0   2020-05-18
1   2020-06-22
2   2019-07-11
3   2018-03-01
4   2021-01-21
5   2021-05-05
6   2021-09-11
Name: dt, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

---

```
Start = '2020-05' 
End = '2021-09' 

Start = pd.to_datetime(Start)
End = pd.to_datetime(End)
End = End+np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Use `loc` to select only dates between `Start` and `End` timestamp.

```
dt_df.loc[(dt_df['dt'] - Start >= np.timedelta64(0,'D')) & (dt_df['dt'] - End <= np.timedelta64(0, 'D'))]
```

Output:

```
          dt  group
0 2020-05-18      1
1 2020-06-22      1
4 2021-01-21      2
5 2021-05-05      2
6 2021-09-11      2
```

Comment: Date column appears as NaT when I run this. Also, the group column isn't being accounted for. @ceruler

Comment: When I run all of the code (including the dummy code I wrote) I am not having this issue. Are you making sure the column is a pandas datetime?

Comment: Can also use `df[df["Date"].between(Start, pd.Timestamp(End)+pd.offsets.MonthEnd())]`.